# Adding Project to Java Build Path

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import, buildpath

I am currently working on an Android project (let's call it project A), and i want to add an already existing project (B) to my A-project, so that i can use the methods of project B.
First I tried adding the project via the Java Build Path, but that was impossible, because my original Project-B-Folder was just a default-project, and not a java-project.
I changed it to be a java-project, and then i added it in my java build path of project A.

Now when I did this the first time, it worked quite well for me. The Files in the Project-B-Folder turned into Packages, which i could import into my .java-files from Project A. Eclipse found the packages while i was typing them, but when i saved the file, it showed the "The import XXX cannot be resolved error".
I decided to redo all the build path stuff, but now, all my folders in Project B remain to be folders, and won't turn into packages. And in Project A, I cannot find them via the import command, although i have added the project B to my Java Build Path again.

Do you have any help for me? Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in atleast two ways as I know. This answer assumes that you are using Eclipse.

1. Mark project B as a library project and add it as a dependency through the `Android` tab in the project properties.
2. Export the project-B into a library JAR and add the jar into the `\libs` folder and then to the build path of Project-A

In the first case, you have the opportunity to make changes to the library project and avail the latest updates in your dependent project after a clean up. To use this method, right click on the project folder, and select properties. The in the Android tab on the left, tick the check-box which says `Is Library`. Once this is done, go to project A, which is the dependent project and reach the Android tab through the same menu. Then under Library, click `Add` and select Project-B as a dependency. Clean up both the projects and build them. You are ready to go.

In the second case, click on Project-B and go through `File -> Export -> Java -> Jar File`. Then choose a destination folder and generate a jar. Once the jar is created, copy it into the project's `\libs` folder. You may optionally add this into the build path as well, but in normal case it will already be added once you copy it there.

Comment: Well solution 1 does not work for me, my project B is not an android project. Solution 2 worked fine (at least i could finally import the packages i needed). But somehow i am still not able to access any of the classes or methods from these packages. Kinda strange...

Comment: @ZerO In the project properties > Java Build Path > Libraries, under Android Private Libraries, what do you see?

Comment: in properties > Java Build Path > Libraries:
ProjectB.jar
Android 4.2.2
Android Dependencies
Android Private Libraries
.
And under Private Libraries itself i see:
Access Rules: No rules
Native Library Location: None
ProjectB.jar //Path[...]
android-support-v4.jar //Path[...]